# Searching a Table - If a result is found, don't search the next table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bit of a strange question in terms of a query I'm trying to produce.

Basically I need to look in about 14 different databases to see if a specific Contract number exists.  If it does, I need it to return a Yes, but the only thing is, the query takes around 30 minutes each time because it's checking every DB for the same values (the contract number will only exist in one DB), and is only going to get higher as the days go on.

I'd like to change this (if possible) so that if a result is found in Table1, it doesn't need to search in Table2 or Table3 etc for that result. I don't know if this is possible, which is why I thought I'd ask the experts! ;)

Currently my query is:

```
select Id 
INTO #tmpContracts
from Contracts
where CreatedOn >= '2017-06-01'

select  Id,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL1.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL2.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL3.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL4.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL5.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL6.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL7.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL8.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL9.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL10.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL11.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL12.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL13.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL14.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No' END 'ProjectCodeExists'
from #tmpContracts c

drop table tmpContracts
```

Is this possible to do in SQL?  If so, this would hugely decrease the execution time.

Thanks for any replies in advance :)

Comment: Start with reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Have you tried the query in your question?  It looks right to me and may already meet your needs.  You can rely on `CASE` expressions being evaluated in the order in which you write the cases, so a match on an `EXISTS` query should short circuit the remainder of the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subqueries from your query run for each rows. I think it uses a lot of time and resources.

Try to use loop and do update for group of rows which not found earlier.

```
select
  Id,
  0 ProjectCodeExists
into #tmpContracts
from Contracts
where CreatedOn >= '2017-06-01'


declare @dbNum int=1
declare @query varchar(max)

while @dbNum<=14
begin

  if exists(select * from #tmpContracts where ProjectCodeExists=0)
  begin
    set @query='update c set c.ProjectCodeExists=1
      from DimL'+cast(@dbNum as varchar(2))+'.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch
      join #tmpContracts c on CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255))
      where c.ProjectCodeExists=0'

    print @query

    exec(@query)
  end

  set @dbNum=@dbNum+1
end

select *
from #tmpContracts

drop table #tmpContracts
```

My script does the following

```
if exists(select * from #tmpContracts where ProjectCodeExists=0)
  update c set c.ProjectCodeExists=1
  from DimL1.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch
  join #tmpContracts c on CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255))
  where c.ProjectCodeExists=0

if exists(select * from #tmpContracts where ProjectCodeExists=0)
  update c set c.ProjectCodeExists=1
  from DimL2.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch
  join #tmpContracts c on CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255))
  where c.ProjectCodeExists=0

if exists(select * from #tmpContracts where ProjectCodeExists=0)
  update c set c.ProjectCodeExists=1
  from DimL3.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch
  join #tmpContracts c on CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255))
  where c.ProjectCodeExists=0

...

if exists(select * from #tmpContracts where ProjectCodeExists=0)
  update c set c.ProjectCodeExists=1
  from DimL14.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch
  join #tmpContracts c on CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255))
  where c.ProjectCodeExists=0
```

For example. If `#tmpContracts` contains 100 rows then subqueries from your variant of query can run 1400 (100*14) times.

In my variant uses only 14 queries to other DBs.

Comment: Had a look at this, absolutely amazing!  Sadly I can't do the DBNum +1 as my database names are different, I just called them 1, 2, 3 for security.  Implemented the right DB Names and this script runs and returns all of the correct results in 1 second.  Can't thank you enough and I've learnt something too :)

Comment: Yes, it's only an example. And you can write it as I put in the end. Good luck!

Comment: If your tables from DBs have the same structure then I think you can use a CURSOR which returns names of DBs. And after that you can use loop for generate and execute script for each DB. It's one more idea how to optimize your code. )

Answer (score 1):

I think this modification will boost your query:

```
select  Id,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL1.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL2.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL3.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL4.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL5.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL6.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL7.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL8.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL9.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL10.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL11.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL12.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL13.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ch.CH_CODE from DimL14.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE
    'No' END END END END END END END END END END END END END END 'ProjectCodeExists'
from #tmpContracts c
```

I just nested all `case`s. It should stop evaluating once any of cases is satisfied.

Comment: This is perhaps one of the only times where I think running a SELECT in the select region of another query is a good idea. Neat

Answer (score 0):

The performance of your above query can be increased just by the below.
(there are so many other ways but I'm giving you the quickest one)

```
select 
Id 
INTO #tmpContracts
from Contracts
where CreatedOn >= '2017-06-01'


select  Id,
        CASE WHEN 
            (select COUNT(1) from DimL1.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL2.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)))
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL3.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)))
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL4.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)))
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL5.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL6.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL7.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL8.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL9.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL10.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL11.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL12.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL13.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            +(select COUNT(1) from DimL14.dbo.CST_COSTHEADER ch where CAST(c.Id as varchar(255)) = CAST(ch.CH_CODE as varchar(255)) )
            > 0 THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No' END 'ProjectCodeExists'
from #tmpContracts c

drop table tmpContracts
```

Answer (score 0):

While I appreciate the other answers are helping with what you've directly posted, I think they're a band aid to a much deeper problem with the way your database data is structured, and how you're querying it

There's no way on earth that looking in 14 different tables for a single, suitably indexed value should take 30 minutes, regardless of whether they're in different databases or not. Even if you had ten thousand contracts in your temp table, joining to just 14 other tables, should not take 30 minutes - and these aren't even joins in the sense of "i have some data in each table that I want out" - these are associations in the sense of "does this table have any data I'm interested in?" (that's a question that can be answered by an index without even hitting the table)

I note your queries convert the datatype of the column being searched - do not do this, as it usually knocks out any ability to use an index on that column. If ch.CH_CODE is a guid (for example), then make sure your c.Id is also a guid (do it when you make the contracts temp table) and then you're not converting potentially billions of rows and looking through them all; your db can simply do an index lookup to know the entire answer to the query "does value X exist in the table". If you take nothing else away from this post, take this: *"indexes or not, if you have a single search term that is data type X, and a billion rows to look in of data type Y, it is ALWAYS better to convert the single type X into type Y than convert a billion Ys into X"*

If you're going to persist with breaking your data up this way, then consider having a marker in the contracts table that tells you where to find the data you're looking for. I strongly recommend you reconsider your data storage strategy though, so you aren't having to run queries that answer the question of "hmmm.. now which of these thousand tables did I leave my data in?" - you should KNOW where your data is

Comment: Hello Caius, I appreciate your answer.  It never even crossed my mind to convert the column when doing the first insert.  I'll remember that for next time.  I do know where the data goes (I used DimL1, 2 etc for this example) as the DB's are named relevantly, but dependant on the currency the client uses, that's where the data will post to, and I needed this to check something over all databases in one go.  Either way, one of the answers above solved the query, but thanks for your time in replying :) Appreciate it

Comment: So, you effectively do know where the data is, based on the currency? Why not use the contract's currency as a driver to know which table to look in? :)